Documentation-only sites do not work if baseUrl is not
A docusaurus site (v2) without a landing page and documentation as the index page does not work if baseUrl is other than /.
It seems like @docusarus-utils.normalizeUrl is generating double forward slashes when routeBasePath is set to a single '/' in the docs plugin configuration.enter image description here
